# Is there a command to show whether my laptop graphics card (Intel) can support multiple monitors?

Tags: graphics, multi-monitor, display, intel, intel-graphics

I'm wondering if there is a way to show whether my laptop can support two monitors.

I have a laptop with Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller running on a Lenovo Thinkpad with a Core i5 CPU.

I failed to find with searches if my hardware can support two monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Run `xrandr` and count the available outputs.

Comment: However, there is no guarantee that all the outputs listed by xrandr are actually wired to physical connectors. Having multiple outputs indicated by xrandr is a necessary condition for multi-display support, but not always a sufficient one.